replication from source to target db ok and did initial load as auto.reload=true and initial.load.create.first=true but after load, DS stops
I have setup the replication from source to target db works (SQL Server to Mysql) and did the initial load using auto.reload=true and initial.load.create.first=true but after full load gets completed.
SymmDS tries to create tables all the tables again and errors are logged in log file.
what should be done to avoid this and resume the replication post load.

create sym tables
D:\replication\bin\symadmin --engine mssql-000 create-sym-tables
insert config

insert into sym_node (node_id,node_group_id,external_id,sync_enabled,sync_url,schema_version,symmetric_version, database_type,database_version,batch_to_send_count, batch_in_error_count,created_at_node_id)
  values ('002','azure','002',1,null,null,null,null,null,0,0,'000');`

insert into sym_node_security (node_id,node_password,registration_enabled,registration_time,initial_load_enabled,initial_load_time, created_at_node_id) 
values ('002','5d1c92bbacbe2edb9e1ca5dbb0e481',1,null,1,current_timestamp,'000');

insert into sym_node_group (node_group_id) values ('azure');
 
insert into sym_node_group_link (source_node_group_id, target_node_group_id, data_event_action) values ('mssql', 'azure', 'W');

insert into sym_channel (channel_id, processing_order, max_batch_size, enabled, description)  values('oe_transaction', 1, 100000, 1, 'convert transaction');

insert into sym_trigger (trigger_id, source_table_name, channel_id, last_update_time, create_time)  values ('mssql_outbound', '*','oe_transaction',current_timestamp,current_timestamp);

insert into sym_router  (router_id,source_node_group_id,target_node_group_id,router_type,create_time,last_update_time)
 values('mssql_2_azure', 'mssql', 'azure', 'default',current_timestamp, current_timestamp);

insert into sym_trigger_router  (trigger_id,router_id,initial_load_order,last_update_time,create_time)
values('mssql_outbound','mssql_2_azure', 100, current_timestamp, current_timestamp);
commit;

D:\replication\bin\dbimport --engine mssql-000 D:\replication\samples\insert_config_azure.sql
3. open registration
D:\replication\bin\symadmin --engine mssql-000 open-registration mysql 001
4. start symmDS
I tried to setup the replication with initial load
Initial load works as it creates all the target tables and starts the load and finishes but after that
replication fails as it tries to create all the tables again. Version is 3.15.6

could you share some logs from both the source and destination node? especially if there are some exceptions and stack traces

I can share, but I confirm there were no errors or stack traces. It is a single install setup connecting to both the source and target and performing the initial load.

You could try turning off deferred constraints, by setting the following parameter to false on the source of the load:
initial.load.defer.create.constraints=false

Thanks Cathy for taking a look! this is not the constraint error. Post initial load completion (all the required data gets loaded into target along with table structure creation), symmDS tries to create tables again through "oe_transaction" channel
